# Как открыть .pdf файл на сайте на мобильном устройстве

Tags: html, pdf

Нужно, чтобы на сайте открывался и отображался **.pdf** файл. В интернете я не нашёл ничего полезного, и, как я понял, это довольно обширная проблема

Comment: Открыть на устройстве и отобразить на сайте — это две абсолютно разные вещи, определитесь что вам надо

Comment: чтобы файл отображался на сайте

Comment: Мобильные браузеры не поддерживают и не должны поддерживать сторонние форматы вроде pdf, поэтому это невозможно

Comment: я видел на сайтах с помощью каких-то дополнительных библиотек можно это реализовать

Comment: Вот и посмотрите на этих сайтах, как они это сделали и какие дополнительные библиотеки использовали

Comment: проблема в том, что я не помню на каких сайтах я это видел, это было давно (пару дней назад)

Comment: «пару дней назад» вполне должно остаться в истории браузера

Comment: А вообще существует такая библиотека https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, но я уже нашёл более простое (для моего случая) решение

Comment: @andreymal pdfjs от мозилы отлично рендерит и на мобилке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам нашёл решение, причем очень простое. Добавляем файл на **Google Drive**, открывает его в новом окне, нажимаем 3 точки и **Встроить**, там копируем ссылку и вставляем её на сайт